# Dealing with ^ symbol in string format python pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, string-formatting

Let's say I have the following df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1^','2','3'],
                   'B':['1^','2','3'],
                   'C':['1^','2','3']})
df

    A   B   C
0   1^  1^  1^
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
```

I want to remove the '^' from the entire dataframe, so I thought using the .replace() method would work:

```
cols_to_check = ['A','B', 'C']
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'^':''}, regex=True)
```

However, this is the output:

```
df

    A   B   C
0   1^  1^  1^
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
```

Nothing happens!
This works with any character other than the carat symbol and it's frustrating me. Here is an example:

```
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'2':''}, regex=True)
df


    A   B   C
0   1^  1^  1^
1           
2   3   3   3
```

Why is the carat symbol so stubborn? Is there a way I can fix this? It would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special character add \

```
df=df.replace({'\^':''}, regex=True)
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
```